# How can I see the front page style files with the wp styles function?

Tags: wordpress

I see refresh to front page but I want see plugin code side. If i run wp_styles() function, i see admin style file. How can i see admin side?

Admin side

```
global $wp_styles; 
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($wp_styles->queue);

output: 
Array
(
   [0] => admin-bar
)
```

Front Side output

```
Array
(
    [0] => astra-theme-css
    [1] => astra-menu-animation
    [2] => wp-block-library
)
```

Comment: Can't use plugin folders to see code?

Comment: Can not see it, but I can see if I print `$wp_styles` on the screen when I make a request to the site with the `file_get_contents ()` by the plugin. This way works well sometimes and sometimes does not work.